# php mysql query out all the words, but not repeat

Tags: php, mysql

Excuse me, I do not make a clear question in english.

I need some mysql query like this: query out all the item names, `UNION` by two tables, but not repeat.

here is my table structure:

table: cxt_20110105

```
item         | ... many columns, but does not affect query, because I just need item.
art          |
collectibles |
furniture    |
books        |
arts         |
books        |
...  many lines...
```

table: cxt_20110106

```
item         | ... many columns, the columns structure is as well as table: cxt_20110105.
art          |
tickets      |
cars         |
furniture    |
tickets      |
cars         |
...  many lines...
```

So

```
mysql_query(//how to write in here?)
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //the result should be: art, collectibles, furniture, books, tickets, cars(every word, but not repeat) ;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) will remove the duplicates for you.

```
SELECT item FROM cxt_20110105
UNION
SELECT item FROM cxt_20110106
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT item FROM cxt_20110105

UNION DISTINCT    <---the important bit.

SELECT item FROM cxt_20110106
```

Comment: From the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html): "The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal."

Comment: I prefer writing explicit queries, to make it clear what's going on. defaults are fine, but seeing it spelled out like this makes it clearer for others.

Comment: Right, DISTINCT is no useful. The answer is such easy. I am not study the basic knowledge well. Thanks.

Comment: I can see your side. My concern is that those who don't know that `DISTINCT` is the default behavior might then assume that `UNION` would behave like `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Hey, man, do not dispute. you two all helpful. Thanks to all of you. Joe Stefanelli is first answer, so give him a mark, and give Marc B a voteup.

Answer (score 0):

feel free to delete this post....I misconstrued what he was asking

```
echo mysql_field_name ( $row , 0 ); //art
```

you can stick it in a loop and exit on failure (no more entries), or go the length of $row

```
$n = count($row);
$i=0;
while ($i<$n) {
  echo mysql_field_name ( $row , $i );
  $i++;
}
```

note, as the array returned by mysql_fetch_array returns both an numeric and text index, $n might be 2x what you need...so $n = int(count($row)/2)

It looks like I may have misunderstood the question though - I was thinking he wanted the field names output within the middle.  Then again, that within a while loop itself wouldn't make sense.  my apologies